# How do I store user's activity in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

I am building a social media app (very simple) an I want to store user's activity in firestore database. I have a collection of "users" and I keep user's id, user's username, user's profile pic there. But I dont think that user's activity should be stored there as well (correct me if I am wrong?)

So I created a new collection called `UserActivity` where I store user's activity. I wanted to store if a user has been searching on a profile so I do the following:

```
const logUserSearch = async (term) => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("userActivity")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("userSearch")
      .add({
        term: term,
        date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      })
  };
```

I think the above query solves the problem with user's search term's. However I want to store if a user has visited a profile. So here is my question: what is the correct way to store if a user visited a profile? Should I add new subcollection "profileVisit", something like that:

```
const logProfileVisit = async (searchTerm, profileId) => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("userActivity")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("profileVisit")
      .doc(profileId) 
      .add({
        source: searchTerm,
        date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      })
  };
```

But then how do I calculate which are the most "popular" profiles? Should I create my database in another way, like this:

```
const logProfileVisit = async (searchTerm, profileId) => {
        await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("userActivity")
          .doc(profileId)
          .collection("profileVisit")
          .add({
            user: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
            source: searchTerm,
            date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          })
      };
```

So that I can easily calculate which are the most "popular" profiles? What about the user case where I need to calculate "top 10 fan profiles" or something similar? I.e. How do I calculate who visited your profile most often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A root level collection "userActivity" (or a sub-collection) should be enough. You can store the activity type as a field instead of sub-collections as shown below:

```
users -> {userId} -> userActivity -> {logId}
(col)     (doc)        (col)          (doc)
```

> But then how do I calculate which are the most "popular" profiles?

You can store a number field in that profile's document and whenever the `logProfileVisit` is called, increment that:

```
const usersCol =  firebase.firestore().collection("users")

const logProfileVisit = async (searchTerm, profileId) => {
  await Promise.all([
    usersCol
      .doc(currentUserId)
      .collection("userActivity")
      .add({
        source: searchTerm,
        date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        type: "profileVisit"
      }),
    usersCol
      .doc(profileUserId)
      .update({
        profileViews: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
      })
  ])
};
```

You can also use [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) while updating these fields so either both the operations fail or pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use firestore -> audit logs -> pub/sub sink -> cloud function -> firestore.

[image]

I explain it a little more at https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/tracking-firestore-user-activity/. Below is the function that listens to the Pub/Sub sink and writes back to Firestore.

```js
import * as firebaseAdmin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export default functions.pubsub
  .topic("firestore-activity")
  .onPublish(async (message) => {
    const { data } = message;
    const { timestamp, protoPayload } = JSON.parse(
      Buffer.from(data, "base64").toString()
    );

    const uid =
      protoPayload.authenticationInfo.thirdPartyPrincipal.payload.user_id;

    const writes = protoPayload.request.writes;

    const activityRef = firebaseAdmin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("activity");

    await Promise.all(
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
      writes.map((write: any) => {
        activityRef.add({ write, timestamp });
      })
    );
  });
```

I then have a collection that looks like the following.

[image]